# wildcard loading for every route in angular

Tags: angular, wildcard, angular-routing

I have added the wildcard route to my application in angular .
The issue is after adding the wildcard.

I'm not sure what is the issue!
 below id the routes array:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'settings', redirectTo: '/settings', pathMatch: 'full' },        
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }       
];
```

Login and setting are modules and they have their own routing files.
Before adding the wildcard and default route, on start the app was redirected to login screen .

But now every url is redirected to PageNotFoundComponent .

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
>   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
>   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every
>   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Please guide!
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the wildcard be the last route in the array?

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the **SAME** route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard route needs to be the **last** one in the array. Right now, when your app boots up, the path is empty, so the router routes to the first specific path that matches the application's routes, i.e. the wildcard route. When you change the order such that the wildcard route is the last one, when your app boots, it will see that it needs to redirect to login on an empty path, **BEFORE** it sees the wildcard route and it will work as intended. Secondly, do not redirect to the same route. Use the specific component for each route that targets a component. Update your routes array like this.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**EDIT**

OP has indicated that they want to use separate routing modules for the different features modules they have in their App. For this, you have two options that I know of. You can either use [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration), **OR** you can declare the routes pertaining to each feature module in its own Routing Module and then **IMPORT** the feature module into your app.module. The approach is demonstrated in the following stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8mkac

Comment: i tried that.updated the question .But still the same issue.The url shows http://localhost:11962/login but the screen load the pagenotfound..

Comment: Use the specific components for `login` and `settings`. I don't understand why you are redirecting to the same route for each of these routes.

Comment: So is it a bug?I have 7-8 modules and each has its own routing module.May be i'll try redirect with wildcard also.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It's intended to work like this. If you wish to load separate routing modules for each each of your modules, why are you adding their routes in root routing module? Just import these modules in your app.module's imports and you will be good to go! Either that, or you can LazyLoad each of these modules!

Comment: Check out this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8mkac, It should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank You ! The stackblitz helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like : Make sure you have all the components created as follows

Never keep the wildcard route at first position, because it will always take wildcard path as default path.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component:AppComponent},
    { path: 'login', component:LoginComponent},
    { path: 'settings', component:SettingsComponent},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Try importing  `RouterModule` as `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

Comment: Might be some issue in routing, can you try importing `RouterModule` as `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

Answer (score 0):

Please use component instead of  wildcards:

```
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent , pathMatch: 'full'}
```